# DirectX End-User Runtimes Redistributable Exit Codes

Tags: c#, directx, redistributable

Can anyone point me to a list of exit codes for the DirectX End-User Runtimes (specifically  the June 2010 version, if it matters)?  I apologize in advance if this is a simple matter (it should be), but apparently my google skills are sub-par as I have been unable to find them.

For bonus points:

I'm trying to use InstallShield LE to create an installer for a game I am working on.  I downloaded the DirectX End-User Redistributable (June 2010).  This redistributable has the user install/extract the DX files to a location they specify with the expectation that the user will then manually run the DXSETUP.exe that is extracted to that location.  I handle this silently in a custom action with a location that I have specified (with the intent to clean up these files in a later custom action).

From here, I would like to run the DXSETUP.exe from the location that I specified and respond appropriately to any errors that it encounters (display a message to the user that will help them with their specific problem).  I'm currently using a C# executable that I have created to run the DXSETUP.exe, which is run from ISLE via a custom action.  Since I couldn't find a list of the possible exit codes for DXSETUP.exe, I decided to display a generic message whenever a non-zero (unsuccessful) exit code is encountered which will contain the exit code returned by DXSETUP.exe.  Normally, I would call it a day and wait until users start contacting me with error codes, but this setup does not cover a very specific case.

Apparently, if the user cancels the DXSETUP.exe, it returns an exit code of 0, which is supposed to indicate success.  I do not know how to detect/deal with this circumstance.  As-is, my game's installer will continue to run happily, leaving the user unable to play the game after the installer finishes due to missing DX files.

I apologize if this came out a bit verbose, but hopefully it clearly and adequately explains my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give the user the chance to cancel by running `dxsetup.exe` with the `/silent` flag. This is recommended as a [best practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416805.aspx#Set_up_silently.__) by Microsoft.

Comment: Be sure to read the 'small installation packages' section. You are pretty much guaranteed not to need the majority of those CAB files for your app. Also be sure to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx) article to make sure you actually need the thing at all.

Comment: Note that the one you downloaded from the MSDN site is a little newer than the one that shipped inside the DirectX SDK (June 2010). Details are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/11/30/dxwebsetup-update.aspx)

Comment: @Ross I did notice that recommendation in the article you linked.  As my company does not currently have any type of legal agreement to tie the DX EULA into (we're still in an early stage of development),  however I was hoping to just run the redistributable normally, i.e. use the prompt provided by Microsoft to handle the user's acceptance/unacceptance of the DX EULA before continuing with the installation.  I simply don't understand why rejection of the EULA prompt results in the redistributable returning a successful exit code.

Comment: @Ross Also, to Microsoft's point of tieing the DX EULA into the game's legal agreements, I did not see any mention of how this is to be accomplished.  I do not see a RTF, TXT, or other such file containing the EULA.  Am I to believe that I'm expected to just run the redistributable, wait for the EULA prompt, then copy the agreement from that prompt?  If this is the case, why would Microsoft make us/me go through the extra trouble?  Am I being unreasonable in thinking this entire process is being made more complicated that it really needs to be?

Comment: @Chuck I did read that section, though I dismissed it as a case of premature optimization for the time being.  As it is now, our installer is only 10MB larger than the full DX runtime redistributable itself, which amounts to a total size of just 105MB.  Granted, smaller is always better, but I plan to worry about that another day.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn is the person who can answer this the best, but I don't believe that the DirectX SDK June 2010 licence agreement, which authorizes you to redistribute the DirectX runtime, requires that you display the DirectX end-user licence agreement. Instead it requires that you "require distributors and external end users to agree to terms that protect it at least as much as this agreement". It's only a problem if you're permitting external users make unrestricted copies of the application. If you're open source, public domain or GPL you're not allowed to include the redist at all.

Comment: @Chuck We definitely do need the runtimes as we use dinput, xaudio, etc., which results in runtime messages indicating that related files are missing if I do not include the redistributable.  I do plan on excluding the CAB files we do not need, as you suggested, at a later time, though.  Thanks for the links and the suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't install DirectInput on any modern version of Windows. You only check for "Windows XP SP2 or later" and you have DirectX 9.0c or later. For [XInput](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/26/xinput-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx), you can choose to use XInput 9.1.0 instead which is already part of the OS on Windows Vista - Windows 8.x. You do need it for [XAudio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx) to support down-level, and perhaps legacy D3DX. That probably amounts to 3-5 MB total, not 105 MB :)

Comment: We at one point had the EULA text files you show to the end-user as their own download, but you could also write a quick utility to extract them from the DirectSetup API for localized versions. Otherwise, the English version is in the DirectX SDK under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Documentation\License Agreements\DirectX End User EULA.txt"

Comment: As for the EULA you as the developer must abide by to use the DirectSetup API, that's in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Documentation\License Agreements\DirectX SDK EULA.txt/.rtf".

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for all the information to both of you.  I suppose I'll be working on reducing the number of files included sooner rather than later.  What are your recommendations, if you have any, regarding responding to specific, unsuccessful exit codes?